# How to install Sharepoint on Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I want to install SharePoint on a Windows 10 Pro PC.
How can I do this, and is there any extra software required?

Comment: If you want to use it for development purposes, you can follow my instructions here https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/214520/22112. I have set up SP2010 successfully on a couple of dev machines this way.

Comment: Here is how to do so from Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869%28office.14%29.aspx
Note this is only for development purposes and the same method works on Windows 10.

Answer (score 9):

You can create VMs on your Win 10 and on this VM-Hyper V - you can install Windows server 2012 and sql server 2012 for installing SP 2013.
 [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee554869.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)   and 
 [Bill Baer Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2012/10/10/setting-up-a-sharepoint-2013-development-environment-101.aspx) 
   may help.

Comment: thankyou !! i will try it.. Is this is the only option  to install sharepoint?

Comment: Yeah ....... It is the requirement of installing SP. You can not install SP in a client machine @kartheekn

Comment: We have a Windows 7 development machine with SharePoint 2010 on it, so it IS possible to install on a client machine - but it requires some extra setup.

Answer (score 1):

Sahil Malik has written a book called [SharePoint 2013 Development Machine](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009Y4QZT8) which give an in-depth overview of how to setup a developer machine for SharePoint development and testing, specifying memory requirements, prerequisites setup, network setup, Active Directory setup, SSDs (you definitely want one), etc.  The book doesn't specifically mention Windows 10, but I've used his advice on two different Windows 10 machines and it all worked great.