# How to install SharePoint 2010 on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: 2010, installation, windows10

I am using SharePoint 2010 on Windows 7. Can anyone please help me to know if we can install SharePoint 2010 on Windows 10 Pro? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you can't have SharePoint 2010 on Windows 10.

Take a look at [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869(office.14).aspx).

These are the system options for SharePoint 2010:

- Install SharePoint on Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2 x64 (or
  Windows Server 2008 R2 x64).
- Use Microsoft Hyper-V and install
  SharePoint on a virtual machine running a Windows Server 2008 Service
  Pack 2 x64 (or Windows Server 2008 R2 x64) guest operating system.
- Install SharePoint on Windows 7 x64, Windows Vista Service Pack 1
  x64, or Windows Vista Service Pack 2 x64.
- Use Microsoft Hyper-V and
  install SharePoint on a virtual machine running a Windows 7 x64,
  Windows Vista Service Pack 1 x64, or Windows Vista Service Pack 2 x64
  guest operating system.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to install SP2010 Foundation on Windows 10 Pro using instructions from MS. They also cover installing the full SP2010 as the only difference is the installer has a different name. The link to the instructions is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869(office.14).aspx

The instructions are for earlier versions of Windows, but they still work for Win 10 Pro.

In case the link dies, here's a shortened version containing the main points:

Copy the SharePointFoundation.exe (or setup.exe) installation file to a folder on the computer where you are installing SharePoint and doing your development, such as in the following path:

```
c:\SharePointFiles
```

Run the installer and install the software prerequisites.

Close the installer

Extract the installation files by opening a Command Prompt window, and then typing the following command at the directory location of the folder where you copied the installation file in the previous step.

```
For SharePoint Foundation 2010:

c:\SharePointFiles\SharePoint /extract:c:\SharePointFiles

For SharePoint Server 2010:

c:\SharePointFiles\OfficeServer /extract:c:\SharePointFiles
```

Using a text editor, open the installation configuration file, `config.xml`, located at the following path **c:\SharePointFiles\files\Setup\config.xml**

```
Add this line inside the <configuration> tag:

<Setting Id="AllowWindowsClientInstall" Value="True"/>
```

Save the configuration file.

This change is what stops the infamous

**This product requires Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2 or above.**

setup error.

You can now run (as administrator) the Setup.cmd file in C:\SharePointFiles

Comment: Small correction (same error is on the original page)  - the file to be executed in the command line should be the same as the one copied - i.e. either both should be named SharePointFoundation.exe or SharePoint.exe (in my case it was SharePoint_SP2_en-us.exe).

Comment: I am still getting same error when I run Sharepoint setup.exe -
The tool was unable to install Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role

Comment: @AmitKumarVerma Sounds like your trying to install it on Windows Server 2016. You cannot do this because these roles no longer exist. SharePoint 2016 is the minimum version that works on Server 2016. One alternative is to drop back to Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Thanks Dean for your quick response. I was installing SharePoint Foundation 2010 on Windows 10